# Queue vs Dequeue in java

Tags: java, data-structures, queue, deque

What is the difference between them? I know that

A queue is designed to have elements inserted at the end of the queue, and elements removed from the beginning of the queue.
Where as Dequeue represents a queue where you can insert and remove elements from both ends of the queue.

But which is more efficient?

Plus what's the difference between them two? Because I have a bit of knowledge about them, what I said above, but I would like to know more about them.

Comment: Efficiency for what?

Comment: I've already saw javadoc but i still didn't get much. so that's why i asked here, if someone can help me...

Comment: Like Thor said. Plus: hit google with both `grepcode java queue` and `grepcode java dequeue` to see the implementational differences.

Comment: @ Junyoung Clare Jang I mean the speed or Which one takes more memory?

Answer (score 69):

Deque is short for "double ended queue".  With an ordinary queue, you add things to one end and take them from the other.  With a double ended queue, you can add things to either end, and take them from either end.  That makes it a bit more versatile; for example, you could use it as a stack if you wanted to.

In terms of efficiency, it really depends on the implementation.  But generally speaking, you wouldn't expect a deque to outperform a queue, because a (single ended) queue could be implemented in a way that doesn't allow objects to be added or removed at the "wrong" end.  Whereas any implementation of a deque would also work as an implementation of a queue.

Comment: I did not understand... What is better for efficiency ? Can we use deque all times instead of queue?

Comment: @byteis8bits My answer says that a deque WON'T be more efficient than a queue.

Comment: @Bogdan add to old thread. `Deque` has functionality of `Queue` (and more e.g.  `Stack` too) so it can be used as replacement of `Queue` (and `Stack`).  Both are interface (aka their method are just abstract with no body ) so depending on implementations (aka how are these methods filled with logic) we can compare efficiency.  So case to case.  Generally `Queue` implementation is simpler so it could be said it's more efficient in this regard. e.g. You can instantiate `Queue` as `new ArrayDeque<>();`   and get less "bloat" methods but you can also instantiate `Deque` as `new ArrayDeque<>();`

Answer (score 8):

Deque and queue are abstract data types that can be implemented in different ways. To talk about performance you have to specify which implementations you want to compare and which operation(s) you're interested in. Even better, do the benchmark yourself with the workload your application has and in the environment you're going to use (hardware, operating system, JVM version).

Since every deque is also a queue, in general you can say that deques can be at most as good as a queues.